# (a) Given the graph below, for each pair of vertices given in (i) and (ii) gi

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

[image]

so I think I've figured out part **a)** but I'm not sure..

my solution is:
**a)** part **i)** $v_1 \rightarrow v_3 \rightarrow v_7 \rightarrow v_5 \rightarrow v_8 \rightarrow v_4 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow v_6$ ?

I'm also not sure where to start on **b)** , I know how to get the degrees (*or at least I think I know how*) I think the deg($v_1$) $= 4$

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the degree of a vertex is the number of edges ending at it, so $deg(v_1) = 4$. Do this for every vertex and calculate the sum $deg(v_1) + ... + deg(v_8)$. Then just count the edges. The sum of degrees is twice the edges because each edge contributes to the degree of two vertices.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do part $a$ ?

Comment: Notice that your answer for a) i. connects $v_1$ to $v_6$ instead of $v_4$, so you will need to find a different path of 8 vertices. If you have found such a path, it is obviously of maximal length. For ii. the longest path I can see right away is only 7 vertices.

Comment: so for $a)$ part $i$ would this work: $v_1 \rightarrow v_5 \rightarrow v_7 \rightarrow v_8 \rightarrow v_6 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow v_4$

Comment: then for $a)$ part $ii)$ I got: $v_1 \rightarrow v_3 \rightarrow v_7 \rightarrow v_4 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow v_6 \rightarrow v_8$

Comment: There is a longer path, containing all vertices. $v_1, v_3, v_7, v_5, v_2, v_6, v_8, v_4$. But I just realized I misread the question, it says "repeats no edges", not "repeats no vertices". So there can be a path longer than 8.

Comment: was my part $ii$ correct?

Comment: I checked it and it was, thanks for your help Andre.